# jQuery serialize form with array

Tags: jquery, serialization

I've got some dynamic form with inputs like

```
<input type="text" name="admins[0]['email']">
<input type="text" name="admins[1]['email']">
<input type="text" name="admins[2]['email']">
```

And so on. When I do `.serializeArray();` on it, They are treated as separated, different names. I would like output to be

```
admins
|
-->0
|  \-->email => value
-->1
|  \-->email => value
-->2
   \-->email => value
```

So "admins" would be single array. Is it possible? (I'm sending data with ajax)

Comment: Take the output of `serializeArray()` and customize it to suit your needs

Comment: Yes really :) http://jsfiddle.net/66A8p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach

```
var serializedArray = {};
$( "input, textarea" ).each( function( i, el ){
  var $field = $( this )
    , rawName = $field.attr( "name" )
    , matches = rawName.match( /^(.+?)\[\d+\]\['(.+)'\]$/ )
    , key
    , subKey
    , value = $field.val()
    , subValue = {]}
    ;

  if( matches ){

    if( !( key in serializedArray ) ){
      serializedArray[key] = [];
    }

    subValue[subKey] = value;
    serializedArray[key].push(subValue);

  } else {
    serializedArray[rawName] = value;

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startsWith` syntax of `jQuery`.

```
var admins = new Array();
$( "input[name^='admins']" ).each(function(i, val){
    // val ==> admins[0]['email']
    // $(this).val() ==> the value of the input
    admins[i][val.substring(val.indexOf("'"), val.length-2);]
});
```

[Jquery startsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

[Jquery each info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).